# How can i setup Megant 2.0 OAuth rest api (login api) in react-native

Tags: react-native, magento2

[image]I'm react-native developer, I'm new to Magento, REST and oauth. I want to use the Magento 2.0 OAuth REST API to login into my app, how can i setup Magento 2.0 rest api to my app and login authentication to login to my app.

Iam getting this token as shown in image, how can i use this token to login authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After login We should pass the response token in headers with url http://www.test.com/Beta/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me. and method GET then[image] we will get the user details as shown in the image